# How to ensure that the terminal window always gets closed after running a specific program?

Tags: bash, terminal, wayland

The `&& exit` suffix can be used in aliases and the `exec` prefix when running a script, but I don't quite know how to make sure that the terminal window is always closed after a certain program.

Terminal windows should only be closed when the program has been invoked by the user, not when used in scripts.

Would be especially useful in [Termux](https://github.com/termux/termux-app) (Android) where I in practice exclusively use w3m (in the past lynx) for reading articles — provides an experience more comparable to a static e-book. A terminal multiplexer such as tmux can be used for "tab-like" browsing, if not supported by a text-based web browser.

---

```
w3m 'https://example.com/' && exit
lynx 'https://example.com/' && exit
```

Comment: Replace `&&` with `;` to execute `exit` always even if the previous program ends with an error code greater than 0.

Comment: @Cyrus As I recall I've been using `&&` in order to be able to read any potential errors (mainly related to websites blocking my useragent or dead domains).

Comment: Another way would be to open the terminal running the command in the first place, without a shell underneath.  This would be similar to exec but with one fewer step.

Comment: @user598527 "As I recall I've been using && in order to be able to read any potential errors" – Then you should make up your mind first what behavior you _exactly_ wish to have and let us know that. You can't have the terminal close immediately, and at the same time, keep it open to read the error.

Comment: @egmont Being able to see any errors isn't relevant, you may ignore my previous statement. I can run any failing commands in a separate environment when needed. The question still stands, sorry for misleading.

Comment: I see. `;` insead of `&&` should do it. Or `exec w3m 'https://example.com/'`.